# How to Tap on native iOS popup to allow Notifications. (Flutter Integration Test)

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

Flutter Driver code has to tap on the native "Allow" button to continue and simulate the correct user behaviour.
See this screenshot. [Native iOS popup before app starts - Allow Notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMxdo.png)

App has not yet completely started and is waiting for this tap.
How does one get the driver to tap on the native iOS popup?

Any suggestions and ideas are welcome.

Here is the code for one attempt to wait for the app before continuing with other tests; it just awaits indefinitely:

```
setUpAll(() async {
  driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
  await driver.waitUntilFirstFrameRasterized();
});
```

Here is another attempt at finding the word "Allow" in the popup and tapping on it:

```
test('Allow app to send Notifications.', () async {
  final allow = find.byTooltip("Allow");
  await delay(750);
  await driver.tap(allow);
});
```

It does not find the word.

The issue is probably that Flutter Driver is not aware of the iOS native popup.

Other tests are very simple once in the app, for example, to tap on fields, enter text, scroll pages, etc.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this feature is currently not possible. Flutter Driver can't interact with native elements (v1.20.4).

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34345

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12561